# HTML: Have two Radio buttons,Select 1, show 3 text area

Tags: jquery, html

I am New to Html,i have two radio buttonS Like "Yes" and "No" when i select "Yes" radio button 3 text area will appear.
rest click on "No" nothing can appear.

anybody can suggest perfect solution through jquery.

Thank you

Comment: would you please provide us the code you already tried

Comment: You can try my answer as well as you can follow this link also http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberjetx/jhvtU/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow my code as below :-

```
     $(function() {
   $("input[name='chkPinNo']").click(function() {
     if ($("#chkYes").is(":checked")) {
        $("#your-companyData").show();
        $("#GSTINNumberData").show();
        $("#GSTINEmailData").show();
     } else {
        $("#your-companyData").hide();
        $("#GSTINNumberData").hide();
        $("#GSTINEmailData").hide()
     }
   });
 });
```

This is html

create div like this

```
<div id="your-companyData">
<label class="ca-label ca-input-label ca-text-label ca-register" for="your-company">Your Company </label> <input class="ca-value ca-input ca-text ca-register" type="text" name="customer[note][your-company]" id="your-company" value="" placeholder=""/>
</div>

<div id="GSTINNumberData">
<label class="ca-label ca-input-label ca-text-label ca-register" for="your-company">GSTIN Number </label> <input class="ca-value ca-input ca-text ca-register" type="text" pattern="[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{4}([a-zA-Z]{1}|[0-9]{1})[0-9]{4}[a‌​-zA-Z]{1}([a-zA-Z]|[‌​0-9]){3}" maxlength="15" [name="customer[last_name]" id="LastName" value="" placeholder=""/> 
</div>
<div id="GSTINEmailData">
<label class="ca-label ca-input-label ca-text-label ca-register" for="your-company">GSTIN Email </label> <input class="ca-value ca-input ca-text ca-register" type="text" name="customer[note][your-company]" id="your-company" value="" />
</div>
```

Comment: jinesh sir... i have another question

Comment: i am working in shopify liquid, ALL the GSTIN details stored in  "GSTIN snippet" that snippet i used in create account page. when i select no radio button , submit button invisible. kindly help how can i show submit button if i select no Radio button.

Comment: when i select yes radio button .. i can see submit button but in case of no radio button .. submit button disappear.